# pocl needs OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opencl, pocl

I'm trying to get an OpenCL application to run on an ARM.
Therefore I'm trying to install the pocl implementation of OpenCL. (and the Khronos ICD loader) I'm running a Linaro 12.11.
Both programs seem to require GL/gl.h header files. Where do I get them from?

Do I really have to install OpenGL for that?

I tried `add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` since there is a package at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/precise/main/base/mesa-common-dev.
But `apt-get install mesa-common-dev` returned "Package 'mesa-common-dev' has no installation candidate". So where would I get it?

Comment: Need to know your GPU. You could possibly use a CPU alternative though.

Comment: As far as I know I don't have a GPU. The CPU is a Cortex A-9 (hf)

Comment: Try `libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: @random try compiling `pocl` from source. Maybe the Ubuntu repositories version of POCL unnecessarily depends on libgl?

Comment: Same result.
"Package 'libgl1-mesa-dev' has no installation candidate"

Comment: @CoffeeandCode maybe I wasn't very clear. Building from source is what I'm trying to do.
But when I run make for the ICD loader, they complain about missing gl.h header files.
Also if I try `../configure --host=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --disable-icd --enable-debug --enable-testsuites=all` for pocl it complains about missing openGL implementation and their header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pocl shouldn't require GL. The only thing that might require it is the cl.hpp header from Khronos that is shipped with pocl. For that mesa headers should do.

Comment: The master himself, that's service :-)

But if cl.hpp required headers the error would occour at pocl - make not at ./configure, right?

The following error occurs at configure of pocl-0.11 `./configure --host=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --disable-icd --enable-debug --enable-testsuites=all`

`...
checking for OpenGL/OpenGL.h... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/pocl-0.11':
configure: error: Please install an OpenGL implementation with gl.h or OpenGL.h. It is required by the C++ bindings.
See `config.log' for more details`

So for me it looks like pocl is asking for it :O

Comment: And in the config.log I found:

`configure:18191: checking OpenGL/OpenGL.h usability

configure:18191: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5

conftest.c:60:27: fatal error: OpenGL/OpenGL.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

configure:18191: $? = 1

configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h */

| #define PACKAGE_NAME "pocl"

| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pocl"

| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.11"`

Comment: Okay, so I put the mesa headers to both `/usr/local/pocl-0.11/GL/gl.h` and `/usr/local/pocl-0.11/OpenGL/OpenGL.h`. But it doesn't seem to be the right place since the configure output stays the same. I also tried the `/usr/local/pocl-0.11/include/OpenGL/OpenGL.h` version and `/etc/OpenGL/OpenGL.h` with setting & exporting the PATH variable without any success. Could you give me a hint where they are expected to be?

Comment: I just found out the header files are expected to be at `/usr/include/GL/*`, `/usr/include/CL/*`. This might be obvious for an experienced Linux user but for the next noob stumbling over that this bit of information might be significant...

Thanks @Pekka for showing me the direction!!